# Bit vector expression extension in Z3

Tags: z3

I have a 32bit bit vector expression. Somehow I want to do a signed or unsigned extension on this expression to a 64bit bit vector. Is there any API I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sign extension:

`Z3_ast Z3_API Z3_mk_sign_ext(__in Z3_context c, __in unsigned i, __in Z3_ast t1);`

https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/api/z3_api.h#L2826

For unsigned extension:

`Z3_ast Z3_API Z3_mk_zero_ext(__in Z3_context c, __in unsigned i, __in Z3_ast t1);`
https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/api/z3_api.h#L2838

These functions are also available in bindings for Python, C#, Java